# Resolve Scenario for duplicate Code

Tags: oop

I have been asked this question in one of my interview.
Lets say I have base class "A". There are four classes "B","C","D","E" those are derived from "A". Now I have one method which is common in class "D" and "E". What is the minimum way that I can write this method with which only class "D" and "E" can use them.
If I write them in base class then it will be visible to class "B" and "C" without reason.

Comment: You can put it into A with package private scope (in terms of java). Then put D, E into the same package and B, C into different one. It's also possible to introduce kinda function, which is separate object and just use that as a member of D and E classes.

Answer (score 0):

You derive an intermediate class from **A** say call it for simplicity `DECommon` which will have this common method for `D` and `E`. Next derive `D` and `E` from it.

```
class A {
}

class DECommon : public A {
     public:
        virtual void newMethodDE() {
            // DO YOUR MAGIC HERE
        }
}

class D : public DECommon {
}

class E : public DECommon {
}
```

Hence D and E still will preserve **is-a** relationship to A, while logic of new common method will be implemented only once in `DECommon` intermediate class.

Comment: glad you liked it, feel free to accept the answer :)